# Which CPU bug is that? Usually `Attempt to execute non-executable address` with unrelated addresses

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, intel, windbg

A pretty usual Windows usermode application crashes in various impossible ways, for example:

1. Attempt to read/write from address from clearly valid `RSP`:

   ```
   Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff
   00007ff6`2a0e6581 488b442428      mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+28h] ss:00000003`f62fe798=0000012d3e796200

   Attempt to write to address 0000000000000000
   00007ff7`a81d78de 4889442430      mov     qword ptr [rsp+30h],rax ss:00000029`293ff4d0=00000029293ff5e8
   ```
2. "Attempt to execute non-executable address" where the address is not even equal to `RIP`!

   ```
   Attempt to execute non-executable address 00007ff60000000a
   00007ff6`a050d940 c744243cffffff7f mov     dword ptr [rsp+3Ch],7FFFFFFFh

   Attempt to execute non-executable address 00007ff7`d6bf5f01
   00007ff7`de335f01 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+28h] ss:000000c5`118fe998=000002619c546930

   Attempt to execute non-executable address 00007ff7`00a05d21
   00007ff7`6ca55d21 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+28h] ss:000000df`a13ff038=00000291867ffb90
   ```
3. For a dessert, jmp crashing on "attempted to write address"

   ```
   Instruction at 0x00007FF6D6CE466C attempted to write address 0x00000048
   00007ff6`d6ce466c e98f68f6ff      jmp     application!libssh2_default_free (00007ff6`d6c4af00)
   ```

There are around discovered 20 clusters (by stack) where the program crashes. Most of them belong to single piece of logic in code.

After a lot of head scratching, I finally discovered that ALL (without any exceptions) affected clients have one of 3 CPU models:

```
Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel
```

I checked two clusters entirely, that's some 700 crashes from more than 100 different clients.

To clarify, it never crashes on AMD or any other Intels.

Can someone identify which specific bug is that? Hopefully I will be able to figure some workaround in code to avoid the crash.

**Update 1:**
The program in question is a multithreaded C++ program. It crashes in code that only works in single thread though. I checked a few dumps and in none of them other threads were active.

When crash occurs, if would often occur inside stock `std::string` and `std::vector` functions, such as `std::vector.resize()`.

It's not doing anything fancy such as self-modifying code. All code is generated by compiler and runs directly from DLL/EXE. It doesn't include any drivers or other kernel mode code.

OS is stock Windows 10 and Windows 11 machines. Clients set them up on their own.

**Update 2:**
My current plan is to try to reduce code until I can corner the bug in some smallish repro. This isn't going to be easy because bug is not reliably reproducible.

> How do you know it's not your error reporting/collecting tool that is failing?

It's hard to be 100% sure but the tool has been reliable for years and it's hard to explain how the problem is only seen on specific CPUs.

> Is other software failing on that nodes?

Unknown.

> maybe you are just looking at stale data

The crashes occur every single day.

> Microsoft distributes microcode updates through Windows Update

We actually require that updates are installed. So I'm confident that on most machines they are in fact installed.

> does the failure occur on every client that has one of these type of CPUs?

This is rather hard to verify.

> How many other types are in your test population

We have all sorts of hardware in client installations. Also, in our development team, there's just one machine with such CPU, and it shows crashes, while others do not.

**Update 3**
I have studied a dump (reproduced identically 3 times on computer in our dev team). The crash stack is:

```
application!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Tidy_init+0xd9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring @ 4610] 
application!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >+0x68 [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring @ 2521] 
application!StringFormatV+0x1f8
...
```

`application!StringFormatV` code:

```
    std::string StringFormatV(const char* a_Format, va_list a_VaList)
    {
        size_t formattedSize = _vscprintf(a_Format, a_VaList) + 1;

        if (1 == formattedSize)
            return "";

        std::vector<char> buffer(formattedSize);
        vsprintf_s(&buffer[0], buffer.size(), a_Format, a_VaList);
        return &buffer[0];
    }

    std::string StringFormat(const char* a_Format, ...)
    {
        va_list vaList;
        va_start(vaList, a_Format);

        return StringFormatV(a_Format, vaList);
    }
```

It crashes on `return &buffer[0];`, where buffer contains a completely reasonable 33 chars + zero terminator string.

According to the crash stack, it crashes even before the string pointer is evaluated, in `_Tidy_init` which basically prepares an empty string before assigning.

Crash reason:

```
application!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Tidy_init+0xd9:
00007ff6`9e44e259 488b442428      mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+28h] ss:000000dc`7a4feeb8=000000dc7a4ff168
00007ff6`1a44e259 <--- Attempt to execute non-executable address
```

It can be seen how RIP is slightly different from reported failure address. This is a typical pattern in these crashes.

I have carefully compared state of all registers to asm code and they look perfectly as if it indeed crashed on this instruction - all previous instructions had their effect on registers/memory, and the next instruction didn't execute.

Comment: Can you show some code from around the cluster?  Is the microcode of these clients up to date?

Comment: Does your program do any cross-modifying code or JIT?  Or perhaps just multi-threading store through a wild pointer could perhaps be corrupting crash info before the debugger has a chance to read it?  Like one CPU raises a #PF page fault exception on a bad pointer, but the code it was executing gets modified by further stores from another core, if the code was in a R+W+X page?  IDK why just one CPU model would be special for that; I wondered if different Windows drivers or even SMM usage by firmware could create different behaviour.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a CPU bug.  Kind of reminds me of the partial register update related bug in Icelake.

Comment: Family 6 Model 165 is Comet Lake S or H, according to https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/cpuid#Big_Cores_.28Client.29

Comment: When you can go further to this level, time to ping Intel support, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/873/processors.html

Comment: You'll reach a ChatGPT agent ;-)

Comment: The errata list for Comet Lake is at https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/615213/615213_012.pdf.  I didn't see anything obviously relevant from a quick skim, but could be worth a careful check.

Comment: Your cores are stepping Q-0 and G-1 in the table, I believe.  Your other one looks to be [Coffee Lake H R0](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/8th-gen-core-spec-update.pdf).

Comment: How do you know it's not your error reporting/collecting tool that is failing? Is other software failing on that nodes? It's entirely possible you stumbled across a CPU bug but surely somebody else would have noticed by now and if only your program crashes, maybe you are just looking at stale data.

Comment: As fuz says, to report this usefully, in addition to the family/model/stepping you will also want to gather the microcode version.  Intel has a [tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/12136/intel-processor-identification-utility-windows-version.html) for this.  I think Microsoft distributes microcode updates through Windows Update, so if the OS is otherwise fully updated (maybe a big if), you probably have the latest microcode too.

Comment: Another question would be - does the failure occur on *every* client that has one of these type of CPUs?  How many other types are in your test population, and do those machines differ in any other way (amount of memory, OS version, etc)?

Comment: Added yet another update.

Comment: Oddly enough I have seen identical circumstances also on a Comet Lake Q0. I don't suppose you managed to figure this one out?

Comment: I'm still narrowing the code that contains the bug. It goes very slowly because each experiment takes around 3 days on average, and some 50% of experiments fail (the problem goes away). Currently reduced to some 20 lines of code, but it contains 2 massive API calls and 1 massive STL piece. Also, the problem stops reproducing if I move it to standalone app. Probably something about code alignments.